# Proof that there is a point on a surface that is not in any tangent plane

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-derivative, graphing-functions, tangent-line

Question give the surface $x^2$ $=$ $y(2+3x+z)$ and ask me to proof that there is a point on that surface that is not in any tangent planes of the surface

I put the graph in Wolfram Alpha and get that there is a double elliptical cone with one pointy-like point

I think that point is the answer with the same idea of 2D graph with a sudden twist having no tangent line

also, I did partial differentiation depending on each variable and get:

$f_x$ $=3y-2x$

$f_y$ $=2+3x+z$

$f_z$ $=y$

if I consider tangent plane formula of:

$f_x(x-a)+f_y(y-b)+f_z(z-c) = 0$

can I find the point by letting $f_x,f_y,f_z$ all equal to $0$ and conclude that the point that satisfies this condition be my point not being in any tangent plane

And can this be the proof?

Answer (score 2):

Replace $z$ by $z-2$. The given equation can then be written as
$$0=x^2-3xy-zy=\left(x-{3\over2}y\right)^2-\left({3\over2}y+{1\over3}z\right)^2+\left({1\over3}z\right)^2\ .$$
Letting
$$u:=x-{3\over2}y,\quad v:={1\over3}z,\quad w:={3\over2}y+{1\over3}z$$
we obtain the equation
$$w^2=u^2+v^2$$
in the $(u,v,w)$-coordinates, and this is indeed a double cone $C$. The origin $O$ is a singularity of $C$, and there is no tangent plane **at** $O$. But contrary to the statement in the title and in the body of the question, each and every tangent plane of $C$ **passes through** $O$.

(The original $(x,y,z)$-coordinates of $O$ are $(0,0,-2)$.

Comment: so the answer in x,y,z coordinates is (0,0,-2) Am I right?

Comment: No; the answer is that there is no such point. The statement you were asked to prove is false.